# < R > Sum elements of a column, based on dates and events in R

Tags: r

I am trying to calculate the lifespan in hours of different pieces in a machine. For that I have the following information:

- Date.
- Hours worked: Hours the machine was on.
- Replacement: (1 or 0) to specify if a replacement took place or not.
- Piece Replaced: Piece X or Y (This machine has different pieces).

Example dataset:

```
set.seed(89)
hoursWorked <- floor(runif(122, min=1, max=16))
Replacement <- floor(runif(122, min=0, max=2))

dt<- as.data.frame(cbind(hoursWorked, Replacement)) %>%
  mutate(PieceReplaced= ifelse(Replacement==1,cbind(c("X", "Y")) ,NA), 
         datesample=seq(as.Date("2020-01-01"), as.Date("2020-05-01"), by="days"))%>%
  select(datesample, everything())
```

So I want to sum the hours the machine was on since the last time the specific piece was replaced. The result would look like:

```
dt$averagetime[1:10] <- c(0,0,2+14, NA, 13+12, 14+12+13+15, 15+12, NA, NA, NA)
```

The pieces are scheduled to be replaced at the start of the day so the hours worked on the replacement day are included for the next replacement

I really appreciate the help I've been stuck with this problem for a while. Thank you!!!

Comment: is it possible to `dput` the first 10 rows of `dt` so that we know how average time was calculated\? as we dont have dplyr to generate the sample dataset.

Answer (score 0):

Continuing with `tidyverse`, you could try the following.

First, use `mutate` and `cumsum` to calculate the cumulative hours for each day. Would not use `group_by` before this, as to include all hours recorded each day, independent of piece replacement.

Then, you can group by `PieceReplaced` and use the difference in the cumulative hours for each piece.

This provides similar results as to output suggested, except for first Y piece which could be considered at least 2 hours with unknown time prior to that point.

```
dt <- as.data.frame(cbind(hoursWorked, Replacement)) %>%
  mutate(PieceReplaced= ifelse(Replacement==1,cbind(c("X", "Y")) ,NA), 
         datesample=seq(as.Date("2020-01-01"), as.Date("2020-05-01"), by="days"))%>%
  select(datesample, everything()) %>%
  mutate(CumHours = lag(cumsum(hoursWorked), default = 0)) %>%
  group_by(PieceReplaced) %>%
  mutate(TimeSinceReplaced = ifelse(Replacement == 1, CumHours - lag(CumHours, default = 0), NA))
```

**Output**

```
# A tibble: 122 x 6
# Groups:   PieceReplaced [3]
    datesample hoursWorked Replacement PieceReplaced CumHours TimeSinceReplaced
    <date>           <dbl>       <dbl> <chr>            <dbl>             <dbl>
  1 2020-01-01           2           1 X                    0                 0
  2 2020-01-02          14           1 Y                    2                 2
  3 2020-01-03          12           1 X                   16                16
  4 2020-01-04          13           0 NA                  28                NA
  5 2020-01-05          15           1 X                   41                25
  6 2020-01-06          12           1 Y                   56                54
  7 2020-01-07           4           1 X                   68                27
  8 2020-01-08           1           0 NA                  72                NA
  9 2020-01-09          15           0 NA                  73                NA
 10 2020-01-10           4           0 NA                  88                NA
 11 2020-01-11           2           0 NA                  92                NA
 12 2020-01-12           8           0 NA                  94                NA
```